# Does the order matter for the two tallest girl to be standing on the left?

Tags: probability

Five girls and four boys are to stand in a row for photo-taking. All of them have different heights.
Find the probability that the two tallest girls are on the left.

The correct answer is 1/72 which suggest that the order between the two tallest girl does not matter. I am thinking that it should matter since they have different heights.

Comment: *the two tallest girls are on the left* doen't mean that the tallest one is on the extreme left.

Comment: @Damien: I agree. But according to my calculations, that means that the correct answer is $\frac{1}{36}$.

Comment: I also obtain $\frac{1}{36}$ if the order doesn't matter. So this implies that the order matters, and that the tallest one *must* be at the extreme left.

Comment: Yes, can I say that the question given is not specific enough? without specifying that the tallest or second tallest must be on the extreme left, it should be assumed that the tallest and second tallest girl can rotate among themselves?

Comment: I would say that the question is ambiguous a little bit!

Comment: The text does NOT indicate that it is important which of the two tallest girls is leftmost. If this is meant, the exercise is clearly ill-posed.

Comment: In general when do we have to consider the order? For example: A bag has three red and four blue balls. If I were to pick two balls one at a time with replacement, the probability that I will get a red and blue ball is case 1: Blue then red = (4/7)(3/7) = 12/49 and case 2: red then blue = (3/7)(4/7) = 12/49. The total probability is Case 1+case 2 = 24/49. However, I know that we don't have to consider the order if the events are independent but in this case, since there is replacement, the events should be independent but why do I still have to consider the order?

Comment: I do not understand your most recent comment.  The punchline should be that order is relevant if you deem order to be relevant.  If you wish to use counting principles to find probabilities, then you must be consistent with your numerator and denominator whether order is or is not relevant.  Often times in most probability questions *it doesn't matter*.  The answer where order is relevant versus the order where order is not relevant is going to be the same.  Here, $\frac{2}{9}\times\frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{\binom{9}{2}}$

Comment: @JMoravitz A good point !

Comment: That said, I would assume that all children are placed randomly in the line (so for the number of constellations , I would assume that the order matters , also the order of the two tallest girls). Then, there are more constellations where the two tallest girls are at the left than costellations where additionally the tallest girl is leftmost.

Comment: @user2661923  Since you took order into consideration, you should have $N = 2!7!$ since there are two ways to arrange the two tallest girls in the leftmost two positions and $7!$ ways to arrange the remaining seven people in the remaining seven positions.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Nice catch, thanks.

Comment: My alternative approach, whose computation agrees with the comments here, would be to compute the probability (combinatorically) as
$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$
where $N$ expresses the number of ways of permuting $(2)$ people and $(7)$ people,  and $D$ expresses the number of ways of permuting $(9)$ people. Thus,
$$\frac{N}{D}=\frac{2! \times 7!}{9!} =\frac{2}{8×9}.$$
As other comments have indicated, $N$ and $D$ must be computed in a consistent manner. I arbitrarily deemed order to matter in my computation, to facilitate the $(7!)$ and $(9!)$ computations.

Comment: Was this problem posed in the English language? This could be simply a translation error. As stated, "the two tallest girls are on the left" means unambiguously that the two tallest girls occupy the two leftmost positions (in some order).